# Dynamic column Alias name in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a way where I could set the column alias name as dynamic DDL

```
CREATE TABLE MATERIAL
(
ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(20),
CURR_VAL VARCHAR(20),
NEW_VAL VARCHAR(20) );


INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES ('MATERIAL DIVISION','AAAA','KKKK');

CREATE TABLE COLUMNS
(
ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(20),
COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(20) );


INSERT INTO COLUMNS VALUES ('MATERIAL DIVISION','ZPAA');
```

NOW

```
SELECT NEW_VAL FROM MATERIAL;
```

would result in

```
NEW_VAL
________
KKKK
```

and

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM MATERIAL A LEFT JOIN COLUMNS B ON (A.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = B.ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
```

results in

```
COLUMN_NAME
___________
ZPAA
```

I would like to replace NEW_VAL with ZPAA. Can anyone please help me to get this results

expecting results

```
ZPAA
_____
KKKK
```

Comment: `select new_val as zpaa from material a left join columns b on a.attribute_name=b.attribute_name`

Comment: You are looking for dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

my solution was:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE MATERIAL
(
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    CURR_VAL VARCHAR(20),
    NEW_VAL VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO MATERIAL VALUES ('MATERIAL DIVISION','AAAA','KKKK');
CREATE TEMP TABLE COLUMNS
(
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO COLUMNS VALUES ('MATERIAL DIVISION','ZPAA');

COMMIT;
BEGIN;
    SELECT retrefcur(FORMAT($query$
        SELECT NEW_VAL AS %s FROM MATERIAL A LEFT JOIN COLUMNS B ON (A.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = B.ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
    $query$,(SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
                FROM MATERIAL A
                    LEFT JOIN COLUMNS B
                    ON (A.ATTRIBUTE_NAME = B.ATTRIBUTE_NAME))),'cur1');
    FETCH ALL IN cur1;
COMMIT;
```

---

I probed this in PostgreSql 10.13

Comment: Can you please share the function script for the above

Comment: The above answer not use function. Execute as is. I use dbeaver like sql client and show two outputs grills, the 2th have the requery result.